# Nhibernate Spatial Oracle Provider

Tags: nhibernate

Is there an Oracle implementation of NHibernate.Spatial?
This http://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Spatial/src/NHibernate.Spatial.Oracle/?sortdir=down says that's not compilabile.

Thanks

Comment: Having a similar problem :(, found any anwser?

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle provider has never been released. It is not compilable because there has been no one available to resume that incomplete code base.